# Snowflake insert on MATCHED or update on NOT MATCHED

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to insert on MATCHED or update on NOT MATCHED in Snowflake?

The documentation states:

```
The command supports semantics for handling the following cases:
Values that match (for updates and deletes).
Values that do not match (for inserts).
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

But I need both `update` and `insert`, and it does not matter on which exactly clause `matched` or `not matched`.

Thanks.

====== UPDATE ======
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
merge into target_table using source_table 
    on target_table.id = source_table.id

    when matched and condition = 1 then 
        update set target_table.description = source_table.description

    when matched and condition != 1 then 
        update set target_table.description = source_table.description
        insert <some data>

    when not matched 
        insert <some data>;
```

Comment: If you are inserting records regardless of whether they match or not, just use the `INSERT` command.  You are looking at the documentation for a `MERGE` which clearly isn't want you want to do.  Also, not sure how you'd update a record without a match, so is that really what you mean in your question?

Comment: @MikeWalton `on matched` I have other condition that defines whether there should be an insert, will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by creating two streams and two separate merge statements.

```
merge into target_table using source_table 
    on target_table.id = source_table.id

    when matched and condition = 1 then 
        update set target_table.description = source_table.description

    when matched and condition != 1 then 
        update set target_table.description = source_table.description
```

```
merge into target_table using source_table 
    on condition = 1

    when not matched 
        insert <some data>;
```

Comment: Clever. `on condition = 1` pushes `matched & on condition !=1` into unmatched.

Comment: What does on condition = 1 mean in this context?

Comment: @JohnJr. Here it means the condition we are filtering on: Let's say, in table "users" we are looking for "activated = 1", which would mean we are filtering activated users. The condition is column "activated"